# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y me estoy haciendo una aplicacion muy sencilla, el problema pasa que cuando intento abrir un Top level desde tkinter me dice: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
Esta es la parte del codigo que me esta dando error y no sé porqué.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3


class account: 

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title = "hola"
        self.wind.geometry("300x440")
        self.wind.config(bg = "black")
        self.wind.resizable(0,0)

        ttk.Button(text = "Register", command=self.register).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = E+W)

    def register(self):
       SecondPage = Toplevel()
       SecondPage.title = "hacked"
       Label(SecondPage, text = "no se").grid(row=0, column=0)
                

window = Tk()
application = account(window)
window.mainloop()
```

error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emma3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Account\Account copy.py", line 20, in register
    SecondPage = Toplevel()
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2621, in __init__
    self.title(root.title())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la linea que dice `self.wind.title = "hola"`.
Para ponerle el titulo a la ventana tendrías que hacer `self.wind.title("hola")`.

Reemplasas el metodo de Tkinter para establecer el titulo por una cadena. Cuando Tkinter intenta llamar a esa funcion, intenta llamar a "hola", y eso no es posible.

Comment: Es algo raro porque si note que algunas personas lo ponian distinto, pero no me habia fallado. Y gracias

Comment: Vi que creas un Toplevel. Supongo que Tkinter intentó tomar el titulo de tu ventana raiz. Por eso te "funciono" antes. Y de nada.